# boost regex recursive

Tags: regex, recursion, boost

I construct a simple recursive regular expression:

```
a(?0)?
```

This regex contains a recursive call `(?0)`.

It should match a string with any arbitrary length filled with 'a' characters. 
`regex_match` only returns `true` for "a" and "aa", but failed to match "aaa" and any string longer than three characters.

Why?
I'm using boost 1.45

Comment: This [works in PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/iL0eJ6/1)... Hmm, that's interesting... Maybe a greediness quirk? `a?(?0)` matches everything (but very slowly).

Answer (score 0):

I had contact to author of boost.regex . 
He tell me that is a bug . 
Any recursive call should avoid use with repeats.
Such as (?N)? or (?N){x,y}